# Device not working after 12V to 5V buck converter

Tags: circuit-design, buck, 12v

I'm kind of upcycling an old radio with radio, Bluetooth and cast features.

The Bluetooth module and the amplifier for the speakers work with 12V so I chose a 12V power supply.  It works well. When I tried to install the FM radio module, it did not work. The module turns on but the audio output is just white noise. I tried the module on a 5V power supply and it worked fine. For the Google Home Mini, which is modded to have a jack output, it doesn't even turn on. It just bootloops, but, like for the FM receiver, it works fine on an external 5V PSU. I tried multiple 12V to 5V buck converters and none of them worked.

EDIT: I checked the voltages after the multiple converters: I have 5V.
I'm a kind of stuck right now.  I tried searching on Google but couldn't find any solutions. Probably I'm too ignorant about my subject.

Here is a diagram of my situation:

[image: Diagram of my electrical + audio setup]

EDIT 2: If I connect directly the Google Home Mini to the 12V power supply (through a buck converter, of course,) it works just fine. If I connect the Google Home Mini with an external 5V power supply to the amplifier (which is connected to the main 12V,) it works too.

The FM module doesn't work with or without the Google Home Mini. It just works with an external power supply.

I'm using the jack output of the FM module, the L,R and ground output of the CSR8645. All my inputs are connected to a passive RCA selector with some RCA cables (which are cut when needed, for example for the Bluetooth module.) The amplifier takes an L,R and gnd input and outputs the same.

Here is a link to an identical in appearance FM receiver.

[Here is a comprehensive datasheet for the CSR8645.](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/806732/CSR/CSR8645/1)

EDIT 3:
Thanks to @AndrewMorton, I found that I have a 10V AC on the supposed 5V DC output. I tried removing the audio amplifier, which is a TPA3116D2, and bingo, and everything works fine.
So now I have to find out how to clear this 10V AC...

Comment: Can you verify tht you have indeed 5V after buck ?

Comment: Yes I checked and I have 5V.  I Edited my post to add this info.

Comment: maybe you have some AC on those 5V that prevents your device to work properly. I let expert help you.

Comment: Do you have an oscilloscope?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy, Unfortunately not :/ I know that this is what would be needed to visualize the problem but I don't have one and I have no way to access it :/

Comment: @InfiniteLooper can you clarify what you just said please  ?

Comment: The Google Home Mini (and maybe the radio module) is designed to drive its speaker and maybe does not work without the speaker. Try it by connecting its speaker to your new wiring.

Comment: Does the FM module work if the Google Home is disconnected from the power supply?

Comment: What kind of radio module it is? Are there instructions how it works or should be connected? What kind of output it has? Same for the other module.

Comment: @Audioguru The Google Home works fine when connected to an external PSU and to the speakers (of the radio) for the sound.

Comment: @user253751 None of them walk individually

Comment: @Justme . I added a link to a similar in appearance FM receiver and specified what I am using to connect modules to speakers.

Comment: If you measure the 5 V on the AC setting of the multimeter while the 5 V circuits are connected, what does it read? (I expect 0 V, but anything else could tell us something.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton. Well, I think we have a lead here... I have a 10V AC (bit less) on the supposed 5V DC

Comment: @AndrewMorton, The GH Mini can boot loop with only the + wire connected... Thats  super weird no ?

Comment: I know the devices are low power, but it would be a good idea to confirm the current supplied by the DCDC buck converter is sufficient to handle the load with a factor of safety. Providing the DCDC converter can handle some inrush current you might want to add a 100uF or 1000uF electrolytic capacitor on the 5V load side to smooth out the DC and help handle any changes in load.

Comment: @ericnutsch Well, I do not have an electrolytic capacitor on hand. I'm not sure about the consequences if I don't add any. Can you tell me more about the use case of this capacitor?

Comment: The CSR8645 does not have normal L, R and ground outputs. Instead it has L+, L-, R+, R- and ground. Sorry, I do not have enough time to read its 114 pages of its datasheet.

Comment: @Charles, If you have any scrap electrical power supplies or motherboards they are usually full of different sizes that you can unsolder and use. You would want to use a new capacitor when you have the option since they do degrade over time. That said I have had very good luck reusing them when in need, especially because the voltage rating and capacitance is nicely printed on the side of each. Here is a video on how a smoothing capacitor works. https://youtu.be/hEXQXvPH8EI?t=47

Comment: @Audioguru well, me neither, I did not find a better one .  My csr8645  is connected to another board which gives me an L,R and gnd output: https://imgur.com/a/Ij5DcDT

But this is not the issue I think : When y remove the amplifier board, it works so I the issue is probably my amplifier board, but what is going on, I don't know  :/

Comment: 5V AC ? really ? after buck converter ? When loaded with or without google board or so ?